# what are the benefits of splitting large file in Hadoop framework

Tags: hadoop

As far as i know that Hadoop is splitting the large files into chunks 
these large files could be text or images, what if I cancelled the splitting function ? is that going to affect the performance of Hadoop ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you're not splitting the data, you don't benefit from parallelizing the computation across Map/Reduce tasks.

Comment: okay, since Hadoop is originally work with text files, if i customized it to work with images like .TIF extension, in that case is it possible to split images ? or i have to cancel splitting function ?

Comment: Hadoop works with any record based binary file. When you transform your TIF images to a `SequenceFile`, you get the splits for free.